# *Configurable* local DNS server?

Tags: dns, local

I would like to have a local DNS server which I can configure in some way. Maybe a php script, which gets the requested hostname and returns the IP. I don't want to have an IP/Hostname list, but I want to generate the IPs in code!
Do you know how to do this?

Comment: PS: For every DNS request, I want to send another request to another server (in the internet) which returns me the IP (it's not a DNS server, of course). So caching is no problem, but I also can't put all IPs in the hosts file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Simple DNS Plus](http://www.simpledns.com) has several [APIs](http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1192) (plain HTTP, .NET, COM, command line) that are easy to use.

For example, you could add an IP-address (A-record) by seding it a simple HTTP request like "http://127.0.0.1:8053/updatehost?host=test.example.com&data=1.2.3.4" - which you could issue from your PHP script with the standard cURL library.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [MyDNS](http://mydns.bboy.net/) is something to look into.
It gets the IPs from a database (MySQL or PostgreSQL).

I don't know if it can be hooked directly to another source.
But maybe it is wiser to decouple that and let the database be updated from the internet-source and let the DNS system query the database.

Answer (score 0):

How about utilizing your hosts file?

Comment: As I said, I don't want a list of ips and hostnames, but I want to generate the IP dynamically in code. And I don't want to code the whole dns protocol on my own.. ;)

Comment: Please Google for the hosts file, there is no implementation. Just a simple text mapping of a hostname to an ip.

Comment: See my comment above. In the hosts file, ther is no implementation, but I want one!!

>>  For every DNS request, I want to send another request to another server (in the internet) which returns me the IP (it's not a DNS server, of course). So caching is no problem, but I also can't put all IPs in the hosts file..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what it is that you want, but many routers have a built in DNS capability which is usually *very* easy to use.